# How do I specify a reply URL using AKS and AAD integration?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-active-directory

I have a Kubernetes (AKS) setup with AAD integration, (there is a server application and client application). When I call kubectl, aauthentication pop up and after confirmed grant to the client app, it shows an error that the reply URL is missing.

How do I pick a reply URL in AAD application registration?

Answer (score -1):

You may have missed any step as documented in [AKS AAD Integration](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/aks/aad-integration.md).

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. There is no need to specify a reply URL.

I use a script to request resources, but I need a manual step to grant these requests on the portal.